# Add Private Pip Wheel File to AMLS Workspace Permissions

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I am working with a customer and they are having trouble getting things working using a wheel file in the Machine Learning workspace.

The DS is running this command

```
whl_url = Environment.add_private_pip_wheel(workspace=ws, file_path='xyz-1.1.1-qwe-none-any.whl', exist_ok=True)
```

And getting this error

```
AzureHttpError: This request is not authorized to perform this operation. ErrorCode: AuthorizationFailure
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthorizationFailure</Code><Message>This request is not authorized to perform this operation.
RequestId:a166d089-901e-0126-42c1-ec6962000000
Time:2020-02-26T16:25:59.3801883Z</Message></Error>
```

But the DS performing this task is listed as a `contributor` in the RBAC permissions `on the MLWS` (and to the `storage account under the MLWS` as well).

I don’t understand what permissions are missing – this seems setup correctly, but doesn’t appear to work for some reason. Could you please help?

Comment: Could you provide more information, please, so we can pull up service logs? Subscription ID, region, workspace ID

Comment: We were able to find the logs for this incident. Could you try resyncing your storage account keys? See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-change-storage-access-key

Comment: Thanks Roope! I have requested the client to try it out.